# 100% CPU Usage in windows service application

Tags: regex, performance, visual-studio-2012, cpu-usage

I am getting the 100% CPU Usage issue in my Windows service application.

I used the performance analyser of Visual Studio 2012 and got the below root cause which is having more than 90% CPU usage and shown as a hot path.

We are reading file from `shared path` and inserting the content of it in DB.
Using `threading mechanism` for it.

We are using `Regexlist` of around 20 `regex` and matching each `regex` of it with file's each line text and if it is matching we are sending that line as an email.

please help if below function can be done in some other way as it is showing as highest CPU usage for the same.

```
private bool ShouldInclude(LogLine logLine)
{
    if (_includeRegexList.Count == 0)
        return true;

    foreach (Regex regex in _includeRegexList)
    {
        if (regex.IsMatch(logLine.Text))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Either your regex is too slow (perhaps it uses too much backtracking) or you've got too many log lines, neither of which matches your regex.

Comment: Alternatively: you're doing a lot of work and it's being processed as fast as possible. What's *wrong* with 100% CPU usage while the service is running? Presumably it's not processing indefinitely; it sounds as though it's just processing as fast as it can...

Comment: The problem may be due to: [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) with one or more of your patterns. You'll need to post your regexes for more useful help.

Comment: Hi guys please find below reged which we are using..
.*[eE][rR][rR][oO][rR].*
.*[eE][xX][cC][eE][pP][tT][iI][oO][nN]*.
.*Full Thread Dump.*
.*possible GC.*
.*left Cluster with senior member.*
.*joined Cluster with senior member.*